# Connect to LDAP with C#

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to figure out how to connect to LDAP via C#.

The only address that I've got is the following:

```
LDAP://CDS.mycompany.com/o=mycompany.com
```

I have tried to follow the following guide:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms257181(v=vs.90).aspx

But they are using a `<user> <pwd> <domain>` for the credentials. Which is the domain?

I have also tried this:

```
DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CDS.mycompany.com/o=mycompany.com");
```

But when I run that, I only get the following:

```
base {System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException} = {System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8007052E): The user name or password is incorrect.

       at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
       at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
       at System.DirectoryServic...
```

What username and password is it asking for? I only want to connect to LDAP, and then just specify a username to get data about that user. No password.

Comment: You need to have a user that has permissions to read from the LDAP. It is a simple login system. Use the `DirectoryEntry(path, user, pass, AuthenticationType)` overload.

Comment: @Nyerguds: And the path Is the LDAP-url? LDAP://CDS.mycompany.com/o=mycompany.com?

Comment: Are you accessing Active Directory, or some other LDAP server?

Comment: @GabrielLuci: I don't know. I just now It's a LDAP-server, and If it's Active Directory I'm not sure.

Comment: I ask because it matters for the path. The path for an AD domain is something like `LDAP://CDS.mycompany.com/DC=CDS,DC=mycompany,DC=com`. But you can try with just the DNS name. Often that's enough to work: `LDAP://CDS.mycompany.com`.